# 1Gbps network maxes out at 100 Mbps

Tags: networking, home-networking, internet-speed

I've been transferring files from my laptop to my PS3 with 15-20 MBps through cable.
Now I have built a new HTPC and I connected it instead of the PS3 (so same cable, same port), and the max speed I get is 11.x MBps.

Network properties shows 1Gbps on both laptop and HTPC. Router shows 1000 Mbps on both connections. Task manager on HTPC shows going to max 99 Mbps.

I should mention that I tried transferring both through windows network devices and ftp (filezilla).

Speed and duplex set to Auto Negotiate. Jumbo frames disabled on HTPC. I tried setting it to 2KB and no difference.

[HTPC config](http://pcpartpicker.com/p/TYY3Q7) - Qualcomm Atheros AR8171/8175 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet

Router: Technicolor TG799vn v2

**Update**

Yesterday I restarted the computers a few times and nothing changed. Today I just tried transferring something and it goes with 38 MBps. What could be the issue?

Comment: It's better to provide your router & HTPC model

Answer (score 1):

11.x MBytes speeds are from a 100Mbit/s negotiated connection, the mode that  your network is running on.

If either of your devices cannot go upto 1Gbit/s, then it won't go beyond that speed. The highest speed you can get is only as much as the lowest speed among all your devices in the question.

Additional factors affecting the speed:

Sometimes Data Compression or Network Overheads can affect the overall speed of the transfer. As for Filezilla, please make sure that compression isn't enabled for Local connections, otherwise there maybe a CPU overhead which may slow down the transmission speed. Hard disk speeds can also be a factor for gigabit connections.

Comment: sorry, wrong "b" on the router speed :) I know the difference between bits and bytes.

Comment: My bad. Excuse me. You can still try to set the Duplex manually to 1Gbit/s Full Duplex. I hope it works.

Comment: Speed and Duplex seem to have up to 100 Mbps and Auto Negotiation on both laptop and HTPC, I've never seen a network card to show 1000. I just looked on my work laptop as well. CPU runs at 1% on HTPC and 3% on laptop. HDD is WD Red, I've added my HTPC configuration

Comment: Gigabit NICs show 1Gbit/s speed as an option(Desktops mostly though). As for the transfer speed, it will only be as high as the lowest speed among the ports and router.

Comment: Do let us know if it worked. :)

Comment: actually I was right, niether the laptop or the HTPC show 1Gbps in Speed & Duplex

Comment: Auto-negotiation is mandatory for Gigabit connections. As such, it cannot be forced on most drivers.

Comment: check my update. today it works without changing anything